# How do you get multiple statements working within the same open office calc cell

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc

I am trying to create a check register in open office. I want the Balance column to remain blank if I don't enter a transaction. If I do enter a transaction I want it to do the math and display the answer. The description of transaction is in column C, column E is credits, column F is debits, column G is balance.

Example... If C7 is blank then G7 is blank, but if C7 has text then G6+E7-F7 would display in G7.

Please help a brother out.
Thank you.

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you itemised or tabulated your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If C7 is blank then G7 is blank, but if C7 has text then G6+E7-F7 would display in G7.

The formula reads pretty much exactly that way.

```
=IF(C7="";"";G6+E7-F7)
```

Drag this formula down to fill the balance in column G as far as you need.

If the balance on one line is empty, then the balance on the next line will show an error because an empty string cannot be computed as a number. To handle this case, you may want to modify the formula to treat the empty balance as 0 instead.

```
=IF(C7="";"";IF(G6="";E7-F7;G6+E7-F7))
```

Or perhaps you want to use the balance of the line before the empty one. This will fail if there are two consecutive blank descriptions.

```
=IF(C7="";"";IF(G6="";G5+E7-F7;G6+E7-F7))
```

What makes sense to me is to keep the same balance, instead of showing the balance as blank on those lines as stated in your question.

```
=IF(C7="";G6;G6+E7-F7)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!